# make HippoCMS talk to AmazonRDS

Tags: hippocms

SO I was following the configuration(following link), and make it works for localhost.
http://www.onehippo.org/7_8/library/deployment/configuring/configuring-hippo-7-for-mysql.html

```
<Resource name="jdbc/repositoryDS" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    maxActive="20" maxIdle="10" minIdle="2" initialSize="2" maxWait="10000"
    testOnBorrow="true" validationQuery="select 1 from dual"
    poolPreparedStatements="true" username="hippo" password="hippo"
    driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hippo?autoReconnect=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8" />
```

However, when i change the configuration to rds ,

```
<Resource name="jdbc/repositoryDS" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
maxActive="20" maxIdle="10" minIdle="2" initialSize="2" maxWait="10000"
testOnBorrow="true" validationQuery="select 1 from dual"
poolPreparedStatements="true" username="rdsUserName" password="rdsPassword"
driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
url="jdbc:mysql://rdsLink:3306/hippo?autoReconnect=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8" />
```

I got such errors like this.

[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] javax.jcr.NamespaceException: wfdropbox: is not a registered namespace prefix.
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.NamespaceRegistryImpl.getURI(NamespaceRegistryImpl.java:467)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hippoecm.repository.jackrabbit.SessionImplHelper.getNamespaceURI(SessionImplHelper.java:183)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hippoecm.repository.jackrabbit.XASessionImpl.getNamespaceURI(XASessionImpl.java:177)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.SessionImpl.getURI(SessionImpl.java:584)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.jackrabbit.spi.commons.conversion.NameParser.parse(NameParser.java:187)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.jackrabbit.spi.commons.conversion.ParsingNameResolver.getQName(ParsingNameResolver.java:64)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.jackrabbit.spi.commons.conversion.CachingNameResolver.getQName(CachingNameResolver.java:76)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hippoecm.repository.jackrabbit.HippoNamePathResolver.getQName(HippoNamePathResolver.java:53)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.SessionImpl.getQName(SessionImpl.java:599)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.jackrabbit.spi.commons.query.qom.QueryObjectModelFactoryImpl.checkNodeTypeName(QueryObjectModelFactoryImpl.java:1009)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.jackrabbit.spi.commons.query.qom.QueryObjectModelFactoryImpl.selector(QueryObjectModelFactoryImpl.java:205)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.jackrabbit.commons.query.sql2.Parser.parseSelector(Parser.java:135)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.jackrabbit.commons.query.sql2.Parser.parseSource(Parser.java:167)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.jackrabbit.commons.query.sql2.Parser.createQueryObjectModel(Parser.java:112)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.jackrabbit.commons.query.sql2.SQL2QOMBuilder.createQueryObjectModel(SQL2QOMBuilder.java:55)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.QOMQueryFactory.createQuery(QOMQueryFactory.java:69)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.CompoundQueryFactory.createQuery(CompoundQueryFactory.java:67)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.QueryManagerImpl$2.perform(QueryManagerImpl.java:95)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.QueryManagerImpl$2.perform(QueryManagerImpl.java:91)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.session.SessionState.perform(SessionState.java:200)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.QueryManagerImpl.perform(QueryManagerImpl.java:197)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.QueryManagerImpl.createQuery(QueryManagerImpl.java:91)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hippoecm.repository.decorating.QueryManagerDecorator.createQuery(QueryManagerDecorator.java:41)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hippoecm.repository.impl.QueryManagerDecorator.createQuery(QueryManagerDecorator.java:39)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.onehippo.cms7.repository.wfdropbox.DropboxDaemonModule.run(DropboxDaemonModule.java:125)

Answer (score 0):

Note that you've cross-posted this and that people are trying to answer you here:
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/hippo-community/NTWpFoDJUxE/UFbMA0IvNWkJ

Comment: I found out the answer, it is because the first time connection time out.